# Error: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding-y"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using ruby 2.4.1 and rails 5.2.2, I want to add bootstrap 4 to my existing project. I removed all the css and js files from assets and just imported bootstrap in my application.scss and required in application.js file. But when page is opened it is giving error:

ActionView::Template::Error (Error: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding-y".
        on line 7 of ../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootstrap-4.2.1/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_alert.scss

> > padding: $alert-padding-y $alert-padding-x;

Comment: check if you have config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb'] in application.rb

Comment: @AsnadAtta Yes i have config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css *.jpg *.png) in application.rb

Comment: did you removed sass gem from gemfile?

Comment: No @wasipeer gem 'sass-rails' is there in my gem file.

Comment: please provide application.scss file

Comment: Thanks all for the help. I just used my required file to be precompiled instead of * in config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css *.jpg *.png). Error gone, that means there is some file conflicting with bootstrap 4. I am trying to find the conflict now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add your asset file in `config.assets.precompile = ['.js', '.css', '*.css.erb']` in application.rb. and check if you have import `sprockets` in `application.scss`

Comment: Weirdly for me, it worked after I unwittingly downgraded `sprockets-rails` by following https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem `Ensure that sprockets-rails is at least v2.3.2` bit. I did a `bundle show sprockets-rails` and it said `3.2.1`, I missed that the major version was higher, assumed it was a new version and changed it, it worked, but through a 3.2.1 => 2.3.2 downgrade in sprockets-rails.